# What are the naming conventions and other standards used while developing a class in php?

Tags: php, oop, class, coding-style

I am pretty new to PHP classes and I want to follow the standard pattern?

Comment: oh dear, PHP naming conventions ... ever seen the function reference ... :p

Comment: The standard functions are a mess, that's true. But when producing new code, it's absolutely possible to stick to a consistent naming and coding style.

Comment: Yeah i know, i was just kidding (see :p ) It's a good question.

Comment: Adding a question mark to a declarative sentence doesn't make it a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zend guidelines are the most popular:

[Zend Naming Conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)

Though really the best advice on naming conventions in any project is simply to pick one that works best for you and your team, and therefor will follow so long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Another popular is the one defined here: http://drupal.org/coding-standards

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to choose a widely used coding convention that is well documented. One such example is the [PEAR coding conventions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) (which include the [PEAR naming conventions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php)). That way you're less likely to encounter stylistic differences among yourself and your team members and you don't need to write and maintain the documentation yourself.